# How to keep a mesh in its original position after applying Curve modifier?

Tags: transforms

I have 3 meshes positioned next to each other, I want to apply the curve modifier on each one of them so that I could bend them in a certain way on the x-axis. But applying the curve modifier changes their position, something to do with the origin. So how do I fix this problem?

By the way imagine three cylinders for the meshes and I want them to bend to look like......well let's say a banana like shape.

Answer (score 0):

The curve modifier makes a given mesh follow a specific curve, this means that the mesh will start at the root of the curve. If you are just looking for a simple bend then i would recommend using the Simple Deform modifier instead. Simple deform lets the mesh retain its original position.

Alternatively you can parent to curve to the object so that the root is always at the origin of the mesh being deformed.

Comment: Yes but the thing is I want to alter 3 meshes at the same time, the curve modifier easily allows that. I just want them to stay in the original position, so that when I use the curve it would be in the form of a shapekey.